# Make returned anonymous function the same instance for each call

Tags: javascript, typescript

The following function returns a new anonymous function for each call.

```
public example() {
    return (): string => {
        return 'hello world';
    };
}

let a = example();
let b = example();

console.log(a === b);
```

The above will print `false`

Is it possible to re-use the same anonymous function without having to assign it to as a property of `this`. So that the function is isolated.

Comment: Why don't you run it?

Comment: @ASDFGerte I've updated my question

Comment: Could you expand on the context? What's the *problem*?

Comment: if there is no closure needed in the anonymous function (as in your current edit), have `example` close over a function and return that every time, e.g. with an IIFE.

Comment: Similar to this: `public example = (() => { let _priv = () => "hello world"; return function(){ return _priv; };})();` - the "oldschool" version of private variables before there was e.g. typescript with `private` (which sounds like a valid alternative, but is apparently unwanted).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I need to pass a function as a value to a template parameter, but that value can not mutate as it triggers change detection in the template. So I need the function to return the same value every time. It's for an Angular app.

Comment: @ASDFGerte oh that's clever. Post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have `example` be a function that closes over the function that is to be returned, by using an IIFE:

```js
let example = (() => {
    let _priv = () => "hello world";
    return function(){ return _priv; };
  })();
  
let a = example();
let b = example();

console.log(a === b);
```

This was one of the methods (if not the method) for private variables before there were alternatives like using typescript's static checks and `private`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as deepEqual from "deep-equal";
```

Try to use: `console.log(deepEqual(a, b);`